# How do I mirror my screen to the TV (cast screen) using Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

I own a Moto G running KitKat and a Chromecast, both are on the same network. The chromecast works for almost everything (Netflix, Youtube, etc) but I can't get the screen casting feature on my Android to work.

If the Chromecast is turned on, I can see a "Cast Screen" button on the android drawer, but upon clicking on it I get an error message that says "Casting Screen to Chromecast Name has failed"

I read a few articles some weeks ago saying that screen casting / mirroring was coming to Chromecast, so when I bought one and it downloaded a firmware update and the feature showed up on my android's screen, I assumed it had been released to the public.

How can I find out why it isn't working?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting your Android device to Chromecast is not officially supported. The Cast Screen tile shows up in [certain conditions](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/27/psa-you-are-not-the-only-one-who-has-seen-the-mysterious-cast-screen-tile-appear-in-quick-settings/) but at the moment it is not possible to cast your screen.

From the original article:

> The Cast Screen tile seems to pop up for users of Nexus and newer Motorola devices when certain Chromecast apps have been used, for example AllCast. It's triggering something in Android related to an incomplete casting feature – that's all we can say for sure.
>
> No one has, to our knowledge, gotten this native screen casting feature to work on a stock device – it just crashes when trying to connect to a Chromecast.  (...) Presumably Google will fix this and expose it to users eventually, but right now all you're seeing is a stub of a future feature.

**UPDATE** - At [Google I/O 2014](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/06/25/io-2014-chromecast-to-get-live-screen-mirroring-casting-from-other-networks-and-google-photo-galleries-soon/) they announced that screen mirroring is coming in a future update of Google Play Services. It is expected that this will roll out in the next few weeks.

Comment: They just announced this at I/O that it will be supported soon.  I actually already used this on a Samsung smart TV my parents bought using my Nexus 5 and my Nexus 10 and it seemed to be working pretty well... only thing I'd say is a bit crappy is I can't stream Play Movies downloaded to the device (though it could play other downloaded video just a software limitation).  Since my parent's don't have great bandwidth but have a 4K TV that was a bit disappointing (surprisingly "4K" streamed from YouTube though and looked amazing).

Comment: Was just trying this with my personal Chromecast though and still getting this error hence finding this post, but hopefully an update to the chromecast rolls out soon to make it work as it would be fun to do some gaming using the phone as the joystick and console.

Comment: Good to see that only after two months there's now some hope :D